# Why am I not able to play the wave file?

Tags: python, pygame, wave

I am working on a audioplayer that uses qr-codes as input. it works until it actually needs to play the audio.wav. Then i get the error "UNknown Wave Format".

```
import cv2
from pytube import YouTube
import pygame

PURPLE = '255, 0, 188'
PATH = 'A:\\VS\\programms\\ai-help'
MUSIC_PATH = 'A:\\VS\\programms\\ai-help\\audio.wav'
link = ''
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) #frequency, size, channels, buffersize
pygame.init()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

def download():
    try:
        yt = YouTube(link)
    except:
        print('Connection error')
    
    try:
        mp3_stream = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        mp3_stream.download(output_path=PATH,filename='audio.wav')
        print('download complete')
    except:
        print('error downloading audiofile')

def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(MUSIC_PATH)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(MUSIC_PATH)
    print('now playing')
```

I already tried using mp3 and changing the sample_frequency and the bitrate, but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Please post only the relevant code lines with all the erors and debug info.  All the YouTube and QR stuff is absolutely unneeded here.

Comment: It seems like you have an mp3 file you call "wav". Try renaming it to "audio.mp3" to see if pygame guesses format better. Delete the old "audio.wav" file to make sure you don't have cruft laying around.

Comment: As for writing questions, you could remove the qr stuff and instead use a hardcoded youtube url. Just download and play. The youtube url may go stale over time, but I don't see a way of getting around that part.

Comment: @tdelaney i already did that and then i just get the error "corrupt mp3 file (bad stream)"

Comment: Can you post a url that fails?

Comment: @tdelaney i am using "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Wg8ySt9tO0"

Comment: `file` showed the file type as `audio.wav: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP`. So, yeah, sloth (below) has a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The file you download is not a `wav` or `mp3` file. Since you download it from youtube, I guess it's either an `mp4a` or `opus` file.

Since pygame does not support these codecs, you'll have to first convert the file to a supported format.

Here's a simple, working example using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python):

```
from pytube import YouTube
import ffmpeg
import pygame

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QbWfgq3PvQ"
audio_file = "input.mp4"
mp3_file = "output.mp3"

yt = YouTube(video_url)
yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(filename=audio_file)

ffmpeg.input(audio_file).output(mp3_file).run()

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3_file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    continue
```

Comment: this returns the error, that ffmpeg has no attribute for input

Comment: sounds like you're using `python-ffmpeg` and not `ffmpeg-python` (yes, those are two different modules).  They work a little different, so replace the `ffmpeg.input...` line with `ffmpeg.FFmpeg().option("y").input(audio_file).output(mp3_file).execute()`

Comment: its still not working. I also tryed using the whole filepath and reinstalled ffmpeg-python and now i get the error "module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'FFmpeg'"

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the support guys. I realy apprechiate it. As the version with ffmpeg didnt worked i now used movviepy to convert the mp4 into a mp3 and now it works. For anyone asking the code is only two lines long...

```
FILECONVERT = AudioFileClip(mp4_file)
FILECONVERT.write_audiofile(mp3_file)
```

with the import

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

Comment: It effectively provides a solution to the problem and shares the code used to implement it. However, adding more context and explanation could enhance its usefulness.